# I'm getting an error "[Product_Name] cannot be found" while trying to filter search results

Tags: c#

I`m gettings this error and I have checked my column name and it is correct,
here is my piece of code:

```
public partial class Search : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StockRecord.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";

    }
{   
    try
    {
      connection.Open();
      DataView DV = new DataView(DT); //DT has been declared as a global variable for a DataTable.
      DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Product_Name LIKE '%{0}%'", radTextBox1.Text);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
      connection.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception S)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("" + S);
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `DataTable` has a column called `Product_Name`? Can you please show the code part that how your `DataTable` declared and filled?

Comment: Yes.  
  {
    private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        public Search()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StockRecord.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";
            
        }

Comment: Paste it on your question with `edit` button under your question. And I don't see any filled part to your `DataTable`.

Comment: Where do you fill your datatable?

Comment: Okay. Do I have to add a fill function to it?

Comment: @EAmarasekara: Yes, you should fill your datatable by `SqlDataAdapter` or anything else.

Comment: Okay! I will do it and get back on this issue. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this:

```
public partial class Search : Form
{
  private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
  DataTable DT = new DataTable();
  public Search()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\StockRecord.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;";

    try
    {
      connection.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Product", connection);
      da.Fill(DT);
      DataView DV = new DataView(DT); //DT has been declared as a global variable for a DataTable.
      DV.RowFilter = String.Format("Product_Name LIKE '%{0}%'", radTextBox1.Text);
      dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
      connection.Close();
     }
     catch (Exception S)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("" + S);
     }
  }
}
```

`Product` is your table name.